# Setting distance in a layout

Tags: android, layout, android-studio-3.0

I would like to make an android layout with 5 input fields and a button.
The distance between the 5 fields must be zero and that there is the same distance between the button, the 5 fields and the edges.

If I use vertical chains for distances, I also move the fields. Is there a way to create a block with the 5 fields so that the vertical chain command does not move them?
Do you have other solutions?

Here is the image for getting an Idea.

[image]

Comment: You tried not to use chain?

Comment: Yes, but the chain distances them all, I want to leave those 5 together.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the 5 input views inside another Constraint Layout or inside a Vertical Layout. With This structure:

```
Constraint{
    Constraint{
        Input1
        Input2
        Input3
        Input4
        Input5
    }
    Button
}
```

If is not clear enough let me know